# Unable to connect to bluetooth device using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth

**Server code:**

```
import bluetooth
server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
port = 1
server_sock.bind(("",port))
server_sock.listen(1)
client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()
print ("Accepted connection from ",address)
data = client_sock.recv(1024)
print ("received [%s]" % data)
client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

**client code:**

```
import bluetooth
bd_addr = " 50:29:f5:36:ed:00 " #bluetooth address of mobile
port = 1
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.connect((bd_addr ,1))
sock.send("hello!!")
sock.close()

Iam getting OS error A which is as shown below
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\katrer2\Bluetooth_communication\Bluetooth\example2.py", line 9, in 
> sock.connect((bd_addr ,1))
> File "C:\Users\katrer2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py"
> line 96, in connect
> bt.connect (self._sockfd,addr,port)
> OSError: A

Python version 3.7.5.

Please help me to find out where I am going wrong or suggest any other solution via which I can connect to a device using Bluetooth.

Comment: Use this approach [examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py), [examples/simple/rfcomm-client.py](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/simple/rfcomm-client.py)

Comment: Iam running the client code in other PC ,during execution ,i passed the parameters -PC  name and Bluetooth mac address of client PC.Im getting the error as python.exe stopped working .Is it correct ?                                                                                                 The server is running -waiting for connection on port 2 .Please help me where iam getting wrong

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be an issue with the pybluez library on Windows 10:

https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/issues/349